# How to add a time tracking feature to an iBeacon project?

Tags: ibeacon, beacon

How do you add a time tracking feature to an iBeacon Project? Additionally, are there any projects with available code that have already implemented this?

I want to implement time tracking for a small project. I want to place a beacon scanner on my door and check at what time I leave my house and when I arrive back at my house.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more complex than it sounds.  The two simplest approaches do not work:

1. Every time your phone detects the beacon assume you are going out or coming back.
2. Every time your phone stops detecting the beacon, assume you are gone.

Approach #1 only works in a very large building where you are always outside radio range unless you are at the door.  This is almost never true, so it fails.  In addition, this technique also fails if you simply  go to the door without exiting or entering.

Approach #2 is more reliable, but only works in a very small building where the beacon is always within radio range.  This is unlikely in anything larger than a single room.  You can improve this by deploying many beacons to ensure coverage.

No solution will ever be perfect.  But you can combine the two approaches to come up with a reasonable guess of when the phone entered and exited the building based on the time of last detection and how long it is reasonably true that someone could be “inside” the the building without detecting the beacon.  The  best algorithm depends on the specifics of the building and the use case.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it. But I still do not understand how to put a time tracking feature ?

Comment: There is no simple answer because the question is really too broad for this forum.  The details of "how" to do this amount architecting an engineering solution.   In order to do that, you would need to think in detail about the specifics of how system would be used (the "use cases"), then create a system design to try and satisfy these use cases.  Engineering analysis would then be needed to predict how well the use cases would be met, identifying any flaws.  This may lead to a need to on change the uses cases to make them more easily implemented with specific engineering solutions.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details I sent it without editing the comment. Ideally,  I want my project to be similar to this [link](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/18/3/922) . I want to be able to replace RFID chips used in running to check finishing times with phones and smartwatches to reduce the event's cost with beacon technology.  
Prototype,  I will use 3 iPhones as they can be converted to an iBeacon device, 2 sensors  (start & finish) and 1 iBeacon(send out signals). Shall I use timestamp? I also want to filter out the highest RSSI as I believe that would be the shortest distance.